# How to display Join (Join the Group) Button in Visualforce page for CollaborationGroup?

Tags: visualforce, collaborationgroup

I am beginner in salesforce. I have a visualforce page where i am displaying all the collaboration groups. Can anyone guide me to display inherent Join Button for groups in that page?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CollaborationGroupMember or CollaborationGroupMemberRequest according to Collaboration Group's status (public, private). You need to add a method in your visualforce page controller.

//vf page

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!add}" value="Join"></apex:commandButton>
```

//controller

```
public PageReference add(){
  if(collaborationGroup.CollaborationType == 'Public'){
    CollaborationGroupMember cgm = new CollaborationGroupMember();
    cgm.CollaborationGroupId = collaborationGroup.Id;
    cgm.CollaborationRole = 'Standard';
    cgm.MemberId = user.Id;
    insert cgm;
  }else if(collaborationGroup.CollaborationType == 'Private'){

    CollaborationGroupMemberRequest cgmr = new CollaborationGroupMemberRequest();
    cgmr.CollaborationGroupId = collaborationGroup.Id;
    cgmr.RequesterId = user.Id;
    insert cgmr;
  }

  return null;
}
```

More info on CollaborationGroupMember; [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_collaborationgroupmember.htm)
More info on CollaborationGroupMemberRequest; [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_collaborationgroupmemberrequest.htm)